# Handlebars is undefined using Require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm using Handlebars with Require.js, but for some reasons, Handlebars is undifined.

My config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        underscore: "lib/underscore-min",               //1.8.3
        backbone: "lib/backbone-min",                   //1.2.3
        jquery: "lib/jquery-2.1.4.min",                 //2.1.4
        marionette: "lib/backbone.marionette.min",      //2.4.3
        handlebars: "lib/handlebars.runtime.amd.min",   //4.0.5

    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "backbone": {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        },
        "jquery": {
            exports: "jquery"
        },
        "marionette": {
            deps: ["backbone", "jquery"],
            exports: "Marionette"
        },
        "handlebars":{
            exports: "Handlebars"
        }
    }
});
```

...and than in the same file:

```
require(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars){
    "use strict";
    console.log(Handlebars); //undefined
});
```

In an other file:

```
define(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars){
    "use strict";

    console.log(Handlebars); //still undefined
});
```

I'm also using precompiled templates, which are working perfectly fine, so I have no idea, what could be the problem.

Thanks in advance!

---- SOLUTION ----

As Rajab pointed out, the problem was that I used `"handlebars"` instead of  `"handlebars.runtime"` so thanks for his help!

Comment: shouldn't you specify the dependencies for the file you are loading ?

Comment: It was just an example, so I only wrote the parts, which were necessary, for solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

> require(["handlebars.runtime"], function(Handlebars){`

instead of

> require(["handlebars"], function(Handlebars){`

and also shim is used only for modules that don't support AMD. Shim completely useless in your example. All these libraries support AMD. For example look at [16](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.2/backbone.js) line in backbone.js:

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
```

or line [1002](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.runtime.amd.js) in handlebars.runtime.amd.js

```
define('handlebars.runtime', ['exports', 'module', './handlebars/base' ... etc
```

All dependencies already inside it. So you need only paths in config:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        underscore: "lib/underscore-min",               
        backbone: "lib/backbone-min",                   
        jquery: "lib/jquery-2.1.4.min",                 
        marionette: "lib/backbone.marionette.min",      
        handlebars: "lib/handlebars.runtime.amd.min",  
   }
}

require(['handlebars.runtime'], function(HandlebarsOrWhateverNameYouWantItStillWillbeHandlebars){
    "use strict";
    console.log(HandlebarsOrWhateverNameYouWantItStillWillbeHandlebars); 
});
```

that's all.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Thanks for the help, and the suggestions!